# How to check if a child component's root is a given component

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have a `ParentComponent` that must have all its children being a `ChildComponent`.

I would make my `ParentComponent` check its `children` types:

```js
import { FunctionComponent, isValidElement } from "react"
import { ChildComponent } from "./ChildComponent"

const ParentComponent: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const childrenToDisplay = Children.toArray(children).filter(child => {
    return isValidElement(child) && child.type === ChildComponent
  })

  return <div>{ childrenToDisplay }</div>
}
```

Which would do the job.

Now, I want to be able to create a component that is using `ChildComponent`:

```js
import { FunctionComponent } from "react"
import { ChildComponent } from "./ChildComponent"

const MyCustomChildComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return <ChildComponent>...</ChildComponent>
}
```

How should I modify `ParentComponent` to make it display `MyCustomChildComponent` ?

In other words, how can I, in `ParentComponent`, check that a child is either a `ChildComponent` or a component that has `ChildComponent` as root component ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  Why are you checking types like this when you are using TS?  That should take care of all the type checking you'll need.

Comment: I'm working on [a table component](https://storybook.libeo.io/?path=/docs/designsystem_components-table-tablebeta-wip--overview).

In the main component (`<TableBeta />`), I need to add some things like `ref`, internal props, etc... on some `<TableRow />`, `<TableCell />` and `<TableHeaderCell />` for some features like sticky header, sticky columns and infinite scroll.

To achieve this, i'm looping over `children` to target the components and use `cloneElement` to add the refs and props.

I want the developers from my team to be able to create components like `<MyTableHeader />`

Comment: And being able to use it like this:

`<TableBeta> <MyTableHeader /> ... </TableBeta>`